# PHP declare encoding gives fatal error?

Tags: php, encoding, declare

Example #3 of Php manual's `declare(encoding)` [(source)](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.declare.php#control-structures.declare.encoding) has this snippet of code:

```
<?php
declare(encoding='ISO-8859-1');
// code here
?>
```

However, when I tried to run the **exact** code above, it doesn't work:

> Fatal error: Encoding declaration pragma must be the very first statement in the script in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\index.php on line 2

The error message asserts that `declare` is not the first statement, but the code shows that there's nothing before it.

What may be causing the error?

How do we fix it?

Comment: Use a hexeditor and check if your script actually starts with `<?`

Comment: @mario, You may want to post that as an answer...